# Preserve text formatting in coldfusion string

Tags: string, coldfusion, string-formatting

I have a coldfusion db field string called #text1# which is formatted with spaces and line feeds to display nicely as follows:

```
<b>FINDINGS:</b> 
The house is red.  
The tree is green.
```

but when i try to load it into a variable and write it to another db using:

```
   <cfquery datasource="srsdb2_DEDR">
     INSERT INTO  Reports ( text1 ) VALUES ( '#text1#')
    </cfquery>
```

it comes out looking like:

```
<b>FINDINGS:</b> The house is red. The tree is green.
```

how can i keep it from discarding info and preserve the formatting?

Comment: Are you sure that the characters are not there? Where are you displaying the text? In a browser? In a textarea field? View the source of your output and what do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check HTMLEditFormat in Adobe live docs.